# Copy a range of data and paste it into a separate sheet cell

Tags: excel, vba

For some reason, the range only copies over the first two rows starting in A1 on sheet "11937" and I need it to start on cell A2 and copy all data up until column AL and paste that data in sheet "STS" starting at C2.

Please help

```
With Sheets("11937")
.Range("A2:AL" & Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row).CopyDestination:=Sheets("STS").Range("C2")
End With
```

Answer (score 1):

Either your Col B is **empty** or `Cells(Rows.Count, "B")` is referring to the `Activesheet` which **may not be** `11937`. Hence it is always advisable to fully qualify your objects.

Here is an example

```
Dim lRow As Long

With Sheets("11937")
    lRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    .Range("A2:AL" & lRow).Copy Destination:=Sheets("STS").Range("C2")
End With
```

Comment: Even with that it still only pastes the two rows including one being the headers, which I do not want...

Comment: Is you col B empty? Try changing `.Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` to `.Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: All the columns have data

Comment: This is strange. Can you step through the code and see what is the value of `LRow`

Comment: Nope that is not necessary

Comment: I thought that (Rows.Count, "B") refers to the last cell in column B that has data

Comment: Yes it does but since it is not fully qualified, it will refer to the active sheet.. which may or may not be `11937`. See [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba) on how to find last row.

Comment: The activesheet is "11937", I still do not understand as why it is not working,...what other information can I post?

Comment: Can you step through the code and check what is the value of `Lrow`?